# a LEX program to identify keywords and convert it into uppercase

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex

Please help me to answer this question.
I want to write a flex program(keyword.l) to identify keywords and convert it into uppercase. I get with this code but there is an error when I run flex by cmd (C:\GnuWin32\bin flex keyword.l)
error is:

> "can't open keyword.l"

```
%{#include<stdio.h>
int i;
%}keyword main|int|scanf|printf|if|else
%%

{keyword} {
for(i=0;i<yyleng;i++)
printf("%c",toupper(yytext[i]));
}
%%

main()
{
yyin=fopen("num.c","r");
yylex();
}

int yywrap()
{
return 1;
}
```

Comment: perhaps your current directory is not the one containing the file keyword.l. List the files in your directory to check. Are you running from the windows command prompt?

Comment: thank you i solved it,but now i face new problem .when i run the a.out file,the application is open then immediately closed!! cant see the output its so fast.

Comment: Have you provided the file `num.c` for it to read? If you haven't it will exit. What is in the file `num.c`?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is perfectly fine.

What might have gone wrong with it is that while saving it you wrote it as keyword.l. However, it would have saved as keyword.l.text so when you are calling with the command flex keyword.l it says it can't open. You shoud rather call for "flex keyword.l.txt" or change the extension to just "flex keyword.l". Then it should work.